# Debug Wrong library or version mismatch

Tags: android, ios, debugging, warnings, apportable

I am trying to debug my iOS to android conversion and find this warning:

warning: .dynamic section for "/Users/MacUser/.apportable/cache/devices/033f426d/libs/libxml2.so" is not at the expected address (wrong library or version mismatch?)
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for 8 libraries, e.g. libdiag.so.
Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?

The thing is the file exists at the path specified. Totally lost as to why this warning is occurring. Any ideas/input? Oh also i forgot to mention i ran the command [info sharedLibrary] it returns nothing

**Un-copied library:**

pull: /system/lib/libxt_native.so -> /Users/MacUser/.apportable/cache/devices/033f426d/libs/libxt_native.so  
failed to copy '/system/lib/libxt_native.so' to '/Users/MacUser/.apportable/cache/devices/033f426d/libs/libxt_native.so': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

try doing `apportable clean_device_cache` and running again

Comment: i have cleaned the device.. however I am afraid to clean the cache as I am unsure if that will clear all app data/cache. Info that I ned saved.

Comment: this won't remove the app state, the option for that is clear_app_state. clean_device_cache clears the cache of device libraries and re-downloads them from the device on the next debug.

Comment: i have issued the following commands [clean][clean_device_cache][clear_app_state][clean_assets] nothing has changed with the debugger I still have the same error.

Comment: I did try uninstall, I still end up with the same issue. I edited the question above to include a pull statement for a un-copied library.Also I would like to add; I have no idea where 'system/lib/...' path is. If anyone knows where it is please share.

Comment: usually, these warnings are harmless. is there something in particular that is going wrong?

Comment: yes, my app loads with activity started blah blah. I get a aqua colored screen for about 2 seconds and then a black screen. The app fully installs to the device but no screen no functionality.

Comment: this is probably not related to that, there's likely a problem elsewhere. is debugging broken due to this issue?